# Unity Hololens project missing SDK (that is certainly installed)

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, hololens-emulator

I made a stackoveflow account just to post about this since it's been bothering me for 3 days time (tinkering after work so not much time every day). And this is my first post so please be forgiving if I break a few rules :)

My problem is that after I have installed and configured everything and I have followed the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/unity-development-overview) I get these errors thrown by VS

[image]

I have researched as much as I can and still nothing. Things I have tried:

- Reinstalling VS
- Reinsatlling and manually installing the Windows 10 SDK
- Adding all the sdk folders to the Path Env. Variable
- Rebuilding the project
- Building a new project
- Changing the version of the UWP

Has anyone else had this issue or know a way to fix it? I really want to start developing for MR after doing a ~10 page documentation on why its the most promising technology...

Comment: Just a shot in the blue: The packages bug in Unity [Packages inside package folder empty](https://forum.unity.com/threads/packages-inside-package-folder-empty.540867/)

Comment: @Kay Thanks, I looked it up but it is not what I need. It has nothing to do with packages as far as I see. Its the SDK dll's giving me trouble...

Comment: Did you select x86 - it is ARM by default.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in the snapshot its ARM. I build it for x86 all the time. But in my frustration that its not working I took the snap in ARM mode after launching VS.